# Изменении текста в странице в зависимости от url, как сделать это?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Собственно как это реализовать? [Пример](http://tun24h.de/)

Попробуйте после слэша ввести любой текст, и смотрите как меняется. Ключевые слова в исходном коде так же, мучаюсь целый день.

**UPDATE:**
Спасибо за ответы но, теперь у меня получается вывести все что находится после знака **?** как скрыть этот знак? Что бы когда вводит **site.com/fdjsfj** отображалось  **fdjsfj** и не нужно было вписывать в url вопросительного знака что бы вывелось.

Comment: Проще написать в обработчик загрузки страницы код,который получает этот необходимый параметр,посредством обычного парсинга url,затем записывает текст в переменную и вставляет в нужный участок страницы информацию

Comment: Да, и создать на сервере все возможные варианты адресов страниц

Comment: Откройте такую страницу `http://tun24h.de/<script type="text/javascript">alert('you hacked');</script>` :)

Comment: Стоит описать ожидаемое поведение в самом вопросе. Ссылки на сайт, на котором надо "смотреть как меняется" - недостаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо в файле .htaccess добавить:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/index.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

и тогда в файле index.php Вы сможете в массиве `$_SERVER` получить всё что после домена введено.

Например в случае адреса:

> site.com/test

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "/test";
```

Comment: Таким путём же придётся статику отдавать ещё через index.php, нет?
Может лучше что-то типа
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`   
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: Согласен. Спасибо. Не подумал про статику